# Bot Framework always fires sames method of Dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm playing with examples of Bot Framework and made a simple Dialog which intends to salute the user. The issue I'm having is that after prompting for user name, the resume method never fires. It always returns to the ConverstationStartedAsync method. Any idea why?

This is the dialog:

```
    public class HelloDialog : IDialog<string>
{

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(ConversationStartedAsync);
    }

    public async Task ConversationStartedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;
        PromptDialog.Text(
            context: context, 
            resume: AfterNameInput, 
            prompt: "Hi! what's your name?", 
            retry: "Sorry, I didn't get that.");

    }

    public async Task AfterNameInput(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var name = await result;
        PromptDialog.Text(context, AfterAskNeed, "Hi {name}. How can I help you?", "Sorry, I didn't get that.", 3);
    }
```

and this is the action in the MessagesController:

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity != null)
        {
            // one of these will have an interface and process it
            switch (activity.GetActivityType())
            {
                case ActivityTypes.Message:
                    try
                    {
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new HelloDialog());
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                    break;

                case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                case ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate:
                case ActivityTypes.Typing:
                case ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData:
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
```

Comment: Is `StartConversationDialog` the same as `HelloDialog`?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry about that, I'll correct the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what happened but I could solve it by uninstalling the package Microsoft.Bot.Builder (v3.0) and then upgrading in to v3.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me when I made a mistake in the code, then fixed and redeployed the code. However, because Bot Framework saves the state, you can get stuck using the old logic.

On Facebook, you can restart clear the saved state by typing /deleteprofile, and in the emulator just by creating a new conversation or closing/reopening the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

[image]As MSDN said it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow):

> Dialog lifecycle
>
> When a dialog is invoked, it takes control of the
> conversation flow. Every new message will be subject to processing by
> that dialog until it either closes or redirects to another dialog. In
> C#, you can use context.Wait() to specify the callback to invoke the
> next time the user sends a message. To close a dialog and remove it
> from the stack (thereby sending the user back to the prior dialog in
> the stack), use context.Done(). You must end every dialog method with
> context.Wait(), context.Fail(), context.Done(), or some redirection
> directive such as context.Forward() or context.Call(). A dialog method
> that does not end with one of these will result in an error (because
> the framework does not know what action to take the next time the user
> sends a message).

**The solution is to gracefully exit the Dialog,
see the code below for a complete example**

```
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
            public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
            {
                context.Wait(ConversationStartedAsync);
            }

            public async Task ConversationStartedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
            {
                var message = await argument;
                PromptDialog.Text(
                    context: context,
                    resume: AfterNameInput,
                    prompt: "Hi! what's your name?",
                    retry: "Sorry, I didn't get that.");

            }

            public async Task AfterNameInput(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
            {
                var name = await result;
            //Set value in the context, like holding value in ASP.NET Session
            context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("Name", name);

                PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.ResumeAfterTakingGender, new[] { "Male", "Female" }, "Please enter your gender", "I am sorry I didn't get that, try selecting one of the options below", 3);
            }

        private async Task ResumeAfterTakingGender(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            string gender = await result;

            string name = string.Empty;
            
            //Get the data from the context
            context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<string>("Name", out name);

            await context.PostAsync($"Hi {name} you are a {gender}");

            //Gracefully exit the dialog, because its implementing the IDialog<object>, so use 
            context.Done<object>(null);
        }
      }
    }
```